# How can I see the current Database Mail configuration?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

Our SQL Server (2008) instance is configured to send mail and everything is working correctly, but I can't figure out how to view the existing configuration, in particular the SMTP server.

From SSMS I can only start the configuration wizard, and I can't find anything online - plenty of info on how to set it up but nothing on how to view the current settings.

How can I view the existing settings?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you open the Database Mail Configuration Wizard again, on the **Select Configuration Task**, the second option should be to **Manage Database Mail accounts and profiles**, select this option and click next. You should now be on the **Manage Profile and Accounts** step, select **View, change, or delete an existing account** and click next. You should be able to view the different accounts and their corresponding smtp server settings.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be simple but too often wizards will start changing stuff before you know it :)

Answer (score 70):

+1 to [@jsauni](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47061/22336) for the wizard

You can also use the following system functions.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_configure_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profile_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_principalprofile_sp;
```

The wizard is probably easier to follow but these will give you everything at once without having to go back and forth through the wizard.  I find it a bit cumbersome. :)

Answer (score 29):

You can also query this data with a select statement:

```
select *
from msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile p 
join msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount pa on p.profile_id = pa.profile_id 
join msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a on pa.account_id = a.account_id 
join msdb.dbo.sysmail_server s on a.account_id = s.account_id
```

If it is a migration that would require you to look this info up, I'd suggest the absurdly simple [DBA Tools: Copy db Mail](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaDbMail/).