# DatabaseMail didn't start when an email is queued

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-mail

This is about SQL Server 2005.  I have configured SQL agent jobs to send an email when it failed.  So far I have received email reliably.

However,  I have an weird problem where an email would get queued but not delivered immediately.  As an example, a job failed on April 1 at 9 AM.  When I query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysmail_mailitems
```

It will show the error mail has a send_request date on 2015-04-01 09:01:30.000, however, I just received the email today, and the sent_date is shown as 2015-04-02 10:10:51.000.

I checked the database mail log, and the database mail process did NOT start on 2015-4-1.  It is only started on 2015-04-02 10:10:51.000, and at that time I open the Database Mail dialog box (I did not change anything - I just opened it to check a few settings).

The database mail log (sysmail_event_log)

```
2015-03-22 01:00:18.597 DatabaseMail process is started
2015-03-22 01:10:21.013 DatabaseMail process is shutting down
2015-04-02 10:10:50.393 DatabaseMail process is started
2015-04-02 10:20:53.960 DatabaseMail process is shutting down
```

The previous job error was on 3/22 and the email was sent properly.  The latest error on 4/1 didn't.

The server is not under stressed, and there is no error message in the server log.  It is just the Database Mail process did not start even when a mail is queued for some reason.

Summary:

Expected behaviour:

1. Job failed

   Agent queue an email

   Databasemail process starts

   Email sent

   Databasemail process stops

Actual behaviour:

1. Job failed

   Agent queue an email

   Databasemail process did not start immediately

   Databasemail process decided to start after 2 days for unknown reason

   Email sent, 2 days late

   Databasemail process stops

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log order by log_date desc` and `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems` ?

Comment: Version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Kin sysmail_unsentitems is now empty,  It is shown that the email has a send_request date of 4-1 but the sent_date of 4-2 (more than 24 hours later).

Answer (score 1):

see what happens when you try to send an email using powershell instead.

```
$smtpServer = "200.1.1.223"
$smtpPort = 25
$emailFrom = "donotreply@xxxxx.co.uk"
$emailTo = "mmiorelli@xxxxx.co.uk"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Port = $smtpPort
$subject = "ccatsql" 
$body = "test email from ccatsql " 
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
```

and [checked which .Net versions you have installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

the problem might be in the .NET. Check the windows\applications error log.
I had a similar problem ([see the question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186839/comprehensive-troubleshooting-of-databasemail)) then I installed .NET 3.5 and all started to work nicely.

[image]

[SQL Server 2016 - Database Mail doesn't work without .NET 3.5](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2900323/sql-server-2016-database-mail-doesnt-work-without-net-3-5)

[How can I see the current Database Mail configuration?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/how-can-i-see-the-current-database-mail-configuration)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_configure_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profile_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_principalprofile_sp;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp
```

Have a look at this question and answer:
[Comprehensive troubleshooting of DatabaseMail](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186839/comprehensive-troubleshooting-of-databasemail)