# Database Mail on SQL Server Express 2017

Tags: database-mail, sql-server-express

I followed [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/) to create a database mail for SQL Server Express 2017.

I got it working but before that I had tried to create accounts and different profiles.

How I do I list all database mail profiles id and account ids so I can delete the old messed up ones.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail-configuration-objects?view=sql-server-2017#Add_Tasks) has great explanations of all the stored procedures you need to create, view, or delete profiles and accounts.

Comment: Thanks!  would i have to just delete the account id? Would that take of the Profile associated it with. It didnt specify on the article

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47066/110455

Comment: Perfect thanks exactly what i was looking for